# How to change video controls size?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: first screenshot]

[image: second screenshot]

on first screenshot video player have normal controls
but second video player on the website with same css shows controls like this

// css

```
#videotag{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 1vw;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: please share your code to understand better.  or use https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: that is the code

Comment: i have only two video tag in different files but they have exactly same css

Comment: first file with normal video controls is .html

Comment: second one is .php file

Comment: Can you check the video resolutions of those 2 files? Sometimes browser would zoom out(for high res. vidoes) and in doing so they would scale the controls proportionately

Comment: they are the same exactly same but in different files first is .html and second is .php tha is all i don't have any other tag inside those two files just video tags

Answer (score 2):

The video player will be responsive and scale up and down If the width property is set to 100%

```
video {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

And if you want to prevent video player to scale up to be larger than its original size than you can use `max-width` property for it:

```
video {
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to declare the css as **id** (*#videotag*). So you can only use it fore ONCE element (in your example for the first video).

You have to create it as a **class** (*.videotag*), so you can use the css settings multiple times.

```
.videotag{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 1vw;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    outline: none;
}
```

For more information look [here](https://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/classid/)

Comment: i changed to .videotag but still same effect (

Comment: Did you switch from `id="videotag"` to `class="videotag"` by your videos? Then with `.videotag` it is a class and no more an id

Comment: yes i change id="videotag" to class="videotag" but not working

Comment: Then make an own css class for the second video, e.g. *.videotag1* and copy **all** css attributes from .videotag there.